# How can I overload the << operator to make it read from a stream?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

The questions to overload the >>\<< operators to make them read/write from/to a stream?

can anyone explain how to do this please

Answer (score 1):

Define

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Foo const &x)
{
    // write a representation of x to out
    // you can use << on x's members

    return out;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Foo &x)
{
    // read a representation of a Foo from in
    // and use it to modify x

    return in;
}
```

appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just define `operator >>` or `operator <<`?

Comment: Obviously,OP wants to write custom class objects to the streams over here.